# Can you explain on theme jsPDF? How to write code where be generated by the file and sent in the mail which will indicate the user.

Tags: jspdf

Can you explain on theme jsPDF? How to write code where  be generated by the file and sent in the mail which will indicate the user. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you are on about how to create a jsPDF file that is generated by Javascript and then sent by email to a user, this is certainly possible. You could use the example script below and then use a server to send the form to the user using PHP for example, such as [PHPMailer](https://sourceforge.net/projects/phpmailer/). You would obviously need to get the name of the user stored in a variable and pass this into the PHP request for sending the form.

Sample taken from [jsPDF Example](https://parall.ax/products/jspdf)

```
var doc = new jsPDF();
doc.setFontSize(22);
doc.text(20,20,'This is a title');
doc.setFontSize(16);
doc.text(20,30,'This is some normal sized text underneath.');
```